How to initiate Vue v-checkbox as false instead of empty string on load?
Right now I have code like the following:
<v-checkbox
   label="Consent?"
   v-model="form[consent]" ></v-checkbox>

form is just an empty object on start
form:
{
  consent: ""
}

I want gender to be false on load instead of "".  Is there an easy way to do this?

Have you tried with the false-value? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-checkbox/#props

Seems like you want VCheckbox to fix a type error in your form data. Is that right? I don't think it works that way.

Not sure understand your issue correctly?
Do you want to use a boolean value instead of a string value?
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <p>{{ profile.gender }}</p>
    <v-checkbox v-model="profile.gender" label="Gender"></v-checkbox>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        profile: {},
      }
    },
  }
</script>

https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpVj8EOwiAQRH9lw0kTLfcGm3jyI6wHWrbaSIFQaJoQ/l1sxeqFMG9nsrPXQEbb0rMxxeSRlIQ5HIzkDqtaAbDp2GrleK/QQid9LxacBqYKAYzVXS+xuKMSyRAjoyYbUvKB7bPRM0zHQQuUp5r8B2oCkjfL4PIBFaNbcK3wBrlDIoz+NExybG1v3GLF2WjrQGDHvXQQ1iaCO77bZwVg0XmrNg35jBJCPGQa188KkmD0u4jEg/JSLs/tBX+4auQ=

Yes I want what you showed here but without having to explicitly set the male: false in data.  Is there a way to do that by using an attribute in the template?

@JackJohnson The answer has been updated.
